# How to decode HTML using Swift?

Tags: html, ios, json, swift

How to decode HTML from an API response like [this JSON string](https://api.fabrykasily.pl/v1/guest/landing)
to get clear HTML to put it into webView?

```
<head lang="pl">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0'>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
```

Fully converted HTML: https://pastebin.com/CKhXzYup

I know that firstly I have to cast JSON to dictionary, and then?

Comment: It may just be me, but that doesn't look like [json](http://www.json.org/example.html).  What code have you tried and what error message, or other undesirable behavior did you encounter?

Comment: Yes, it is JSON :) There was no error, I was trying to put url to webview and then get html instead of make request and then cast response to dictionary and get html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get the html string from the dictionary, load it into WKWebView. Eg.:

```
if let htmlString = yourDict["render_page"] as? String{
   let webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.bounds)
   self.view.addSubview(webView)
   webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even suspect that it will decode it :)